# How do I remove part of the HTML markup?

Tags: 8, theming

In my Drupal 8 template, I use `{{ product.variations }}` which produces the following HTML markup.

```html
<div data-drupal-selector="edit-actions" class="form-actions js-form-wrapper form-group" id="edit-actions--2">
  <button class="button--add-to-cart button button--primary js-form-submit form-submit btn btn-primary" data-drupal-selector="edit-submit" type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Ajouter au panier">Ajouter au panier</button>
  <span>Ajouter au panier</span>
</div>
```

How do I remove the `<button>` part from it?

I tried using `{{ product.variations|without('button', 'submit') }}`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: That won't prevent raw html elements from appearing. Without only suppresses render elements. https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/twig-best-practices-preprocess-functions-and-templates

Comment: Use CSS: .form-actions { display: none;}

Comment: @Jorge Montoya I prefer to remove HTML instead of using CSS.

Comment: Why would you need to remove the submit button of a form? What do you need the form for then at all?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, and if my french (google translate :P) is precise.. you wish to remove the add to cart button from your variations.

In that case I see two options. If you wish to just hide the button in some view modes, like a teaser or whatever, just use the `THEME/HOOK_form_commerce_order_item_add_to_cart_form_alter` and try to remove the submit action. Having said that, I can not guarantee the HTML validity of a form without a submit button or how it will work with the form action, since I have not tested it, but I guess it won't be a problem.

On the other hand, if you just want non purchasable variations, you could try [this patch out](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/3084269) and let the issue maintainers know how it worked :D

Let me know what worked for you,

Best Regards

Comment: Maybe `$form['some_submit']['#attributes']['style']['display: none;']` or `$form['some_submit']['#attributes']['class']['element-invisible']`.

Comment: @leymannx The poster wants to remove the html completely so I was thinking something along the lines of $form['some_submit']['#printed'] = TRUE; but to provide exact code I would have to test it first :P

Comment: Then it's `unset($form['some_submit']);`. But as you said: Not sure if form works then anymore and how you will be able to submit it at all.

Comment: Well yeah.. kinda.... I always prefer to set `$form['some_submit']['#printed'] = TRUE;` or `$whateverElement['#printed'] = TRUE` for that matter, when i wish to hide something.